# Criteria API root.join operation. What happen?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity `Provider` and each provider has list of `ProviderLanguage`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = PROVIDER_ID, referencedColumnName = PROVIDER_ID)
private Set<ProviderLanguage> providerLanguages;
```

A part of providers don't have a languages. When i write this code line

```
Join<Provider, Language> prLanJoin = root.join(Provider.PROVIDER_LANGUAGES)
                .join(Language.LANGUAGE);
```

simply unused `prLanJoin` variable, my search result doesn't include froviders that doesn't have languages. But how this line of code effect search result though `prLanJoin` doesn't used anywhere.

When i comment this line it works as expected, at least for me)

P.S I do not use `prLanJoin` join in code any more. I can simply comment this line and code will work.

Thanks.

Comment: what's this liquibase?? is it not in the sync... BTW using .join() eliminates the records which are not in the intersection. So Providers not having languages are not coming up.

Comment: yes I understand how join works.
 

Join<Provider, Language> prLanJoin = root.join(Provider.PROVIDER_LANGUAGES)
                    .join(Language.LANGUAGE); 
            ParameterExpression<Collection> languagesParam = getCriteriaBuilder()
                    .parameter(Collection.class, NewProviderSearchCriteria.LANG_PARAM);
            predicates.add(prLanJoin.get(Language.LANGUAGE_NAME).in(languagesParam));

I do not write such code. Just join.

Comment: in other words this join does not take apart in any Predicate

Comment: when you are selecting your results you are using prLanJoin, don't you?? then it doesn't needs to be in the predicate.

Comment: if it were to be in the predicate, then it would not have been a join as per JPA.

Comment: no i do not use it at all. I can simply comment this line.

Comment: so you have "root" which is not defined. Ok. perhaps provide a complete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too strange at first, after googling I found and here is the answer...

> Acc to specification: Joins can be chained together to navigate to
>   related entities of the target entity without having to create a
>   Join instance for each join.

So even if you are not using the instance, the join method has operated on..may be using the Metamodels

> The target of the join uses the Metamodel class of type EntityType
>   to specify the persistent field or property of the joined entity.

Comment: So when i simply make root.join(..)  it make some operation at once and effect the result?  I use String-Based Queries not sure about Metamodels there.

Comment: I think so... you yourself are pointing to this behaviour and acc to the specs, seems to me, it would.

Comment: perhaps, this is the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you atleast accept or upvote, so any one reading can atleast go through the answer considering it useful.. and may come up with something else.